# What is this piece? 4x4 ring with studs, anyone have a clue for part #?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

[image]

This is simply a ring with 8 studs on it. Anyone know what it is or what set it's from? Can't find it anywhere on BrickLink. No part number visible anywhere on the part. 1x2 tile on the side for extra size perspective.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the [face plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=bb1008#T=C) for a Lego watch. There's a couple different watches this particular piece could have come from, including [this Darth Vader watch](http://brickset.com/sets/2850828-1/Darth-Vader-Watch) and [this Luke Skywalker one](http://brickset.com/sets/2850829-1/Luke-Skywalker-Watch). I'm unable to find an element or design ID for this part though.

Answer (score 4):

This question is now three years old, but I was looking for this part too.

It's [Watch Part, Case Attachment - Bezel Ring with Studs (bb1008)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=bb1008#T=C).

Comment: Note for future visitors: this answer is not a duplicate of the earlier one, as that incorporated information provided only later in this one (the bricklink link).